# mkdir from result of ls

Tags: bash, mkdir, ls

I want to list all **folders** from `/media/movies` and create folders with the same name in `/tmp/movies`
The following snippet works fine for me except for names with spaces, not sure how to quote here

```
mkdir /tmp/movies
cd /tmp/movies/
ls -1 -d /media/share/*/ | xargs mkdir
```

In the names are also parentheses `(` and `)`  and single qutes `'`

## Example

You're Next (2011) (tt1853739)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd /media/movies
for dir in */
do
  mkdir "/tmp/movies/$dir"
done
```

Or on one line:

```
cd /media/movies && for dir in */; do mkdir "/tmp/movies/$dir"; done
```

Comment: works flawless, is accepted if there will be no oneliner

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
find /media/movies -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "mkdir /tmp/\"$(basename {})\"" \;
```

If you have still quoting issues try this:

```
find /media/movies -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f" -exec mkdir "/tmp/{}" \;
```

Comment: this works actually good, but I've also parentheses in my names, which can't be handled by this - how to escape now?

Comment: Running `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir -p /tmp/movies/'{}' \;` from `/media/movies` is much simpler. Note that `/tmp/movies` is created if necessary.

Comment: nope - `cannot create directory '/tmp/movies/media/movies/Fast & Furious Five (2011)': No such file or directory` - as you can see both paths gets combined.

Comment: Did you switch to `/media/movies` first and run `find . ...`, or did you run `find /media/movies ...` from somewhere else? It makes a difference.

Comment: Super useful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-I` option in `xargs` to set exactly where the output from `ls -1` occurs. Then you can put the output inside quotes so that names with spaces are treated as a single word. Try this:

```
ls -1 /media/share/ | xargs -I % mkdir "%"
```

Comment: this works almost perfect, but not for single quotes. Sorry I missed to mention that before in my question